# Are Frieze groups distinct?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I just came across Frieze groups, which describe patterns that extend infinitely along one dimension. There are 7 distinct Frieze groups. Conway named these:

- Hop,
- Step,
- Sidle,
- Spinning Hop,
- Spinning Sidle,
- Jump,
- Spinning Jump

Each of these groups has a unique combination of symmetries:

- Translation,
- Vertical-Reflection,
- Horizontal-Reflection,
- 180-Rotation,
- Glide-Reflection

After playing around with the Cayley graphs for the seven Frieze groups, it looks like some of them are actually isomorphic to one another. For example, Hop and Step both seem to be isomorphic to (ℤ,+). Sidle and Spinning Hop seem to be isomorphic to one another, as well.

If some of these groups are actually isomorphic to one another, how is it that a group with one type of symmetry (Hop: Translation) can be isomorphic to a group with two types of symmetry (Step: Translation, Glide-Reflection)?

Alternately, if all the groups are actually distinct, shouldn't we expect distinct Cayley graphs and/or presentations?

Comment: A liitle detail: $\color{red}{f}$reeze (Freeze is not a person)

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to consider the symmetries of an octagon. It has a 180° rotation. It has a vertical reflection. It has a 45° rotation plus horizontal reflection. Each of these three symmetries generates a subgroup of order 2. So these three subgroups are isomorphic. But that doesn't imply that they must act on the octagon in the same way.  Perhaps the concept you are overlooking is that of a [_group action_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action). (Warning: Wikipedia article makes it harder to understand than it should be.)

Comment: @jeanmarie "frieze", not "freeze".

Comment: According to [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frieze_group#Descriptions_of_the_seven_frieze_groups), the seven frieze groups comprise two isomorphic to the infinite cyclic group, three isomorphic to the infinite dihedral group, one isomorphic to the product of the infinite cyclic group and the cyclic group of order $2$, and one isomorphic to the product of the infinite dihedral group and the cyclic group of order $2$.

Comment: MJD :) :) :) Thanks, I must be influenced by the cold mornings we have here...